# how to configure loadbalancer in fuse cluster with different machine1,machine2 and machine3?

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

Following are the steps i follow to setup cluster in 3 different machine.

**1.** Unzip JBoss fuse in three different folders, so that you have the following configuration:

```
 - machine1/jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187
  - machine2/jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187
  - machine3/jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187
```

**2**. Edit `etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg` and change `rmiRegistryPort`, `rmiServerPort`, assiging an unique port:

```
**#machine1**

rmiRegistryPort = 1099                         
rmiServerPort = 44444                          

**#machine2**

rmiRegistryPort = 1100                         
rmiServerPort = 44445                          

**#machine3**

rmiRegistryPort = 1101                         
rmiServerPort = 44446
```

**3.** Edit `etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg` and change `sshPort`, assiging an unique port:

```
#machine1
sshPort = 8101  
#machine2
sshPort = 8102
#machine3
sshPort = 8103
```

**4.** Edit etc/system.properties. Change karaf.name, org.osgi.service.http.port, activemq.port , assiging an unique port:

```
#machine1
karaf.name = root1                          
org.osgi.service.http.port=8181                    
activemq.port = 61616   

#machine2
karaf.name = root2                         
org.osgi.service.http.port=8182                
activemq.port = 61617   

#machine3
karaf.name = root3                         
org.osgi.service.http.port=8183                    
activemq.port = 61618
```

**5.** start the root1 Container

```
./fuse
```

**6.** And create the Fabric:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root1> fabric:create --new-user administrator --new-user-password password --new-user-role Administrator --zookeeper-password ZooPass1 --resolver manualip --manual-ip 192.168.1.9 --wait-for-provisioning

Above is My root1 machine1 IP Address : 192.168.1.9
```

**7.** Now, start the root2 Container and join the Fabric:

```
./fuse
JBossFuse:karaf@root2> fabric:join 192.168.1.10:2181
Ensemble password: ZooPass1
```

**8.** Now, start the root3 Container and join the Fabric:

```
./fuse
JBossFuse:karaf@root3> fabric:join 192.168.1.11:2181
Ensemble password: ZooPass1
```

**9.**  Run the following command to ensemble:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root1> fabric:ensemble-add root2 root3
This will change of the zookeeper connection string.
Are you sure want to proceed(yes/no):yes

 JBossFuse:karaf@root1> fabric:ensemble-list
[id]
root1
root2
root3
```

Then, i deployed the rest service on all 3 nodes and create the profile also added require profile with `HTTP GETEWAY for load balancer and HA` but request is not gone throgh machine 2 and machine 3. Even i am also not able access machine 1 and machine 2 hawtio console as per give below URL.

```
192.168.1.10:8182/hawtio/login
192.168.1.10:8183/hawtio/login
```

Can anybody help to to achieve load balancing for cluster environment with 3 different machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest -- don't do any of this :) If you're using Fabric8, install one instance of Fuse, do `fabric:create`, then use `container-create-ssh --host localhost` to set up other containers on the same machine. That will automatically take care of all the port conflicts that I suspect are at the root of your problem. Fabric8 uses many, many ports, and trying to fix them all up manually is a ghastly job.

Comment: I am able to achieve loadbalancer on same machine using create 3 nodes. My concern is to achieve it over 3 different machine. Can you provide information that how to configure it over 3 machines?

Comment: If you do it in the recommended way, it won't make any difference where the containers are located (so long as you don't have firewalls, etc., in the way). Install one container. Create the others from that container using container-create-ssh. Create a container to hold the HTTP gateway, which can be an SSH container or a child container, and add the gateway-http profile. That's it. When this doesn't work as expected, it's usually because there's something in the network infrastructure blocking connectivity between the containers, or there is inadequate name-IP consistency across the system.